# How to hot-encode the output (not labels) within a keras sequential model?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, rstudio, one-hot-encoding, generative-adversarial-network

I am building a noise generator for a particular GAN model.
The generator takes a random sequence of 100 floats and returns a sequence of 809 integers. Each integer ranges between 1 and 21. Then it should hot-encode the output so that the final output would be `[809,22]`.

This is the model:

```
######################### Constants #########################
depth=809
kwidth=22
rnd_seq=100
bsize=8L
noise=function(bsize,rnd_seq){tf$random$normal(c(bsize,rnd_seq))}
flt=8
kernels=12
```

```
######################### Model ##########################
model_GAN = function(batch_size,flt,kernels,depth,rnd_seq) {
 prot_input2 = layer_input(shape = c(rnd_seq))
 GAN= prot_input2 %>% 
    layer_dense(depth) %>%
    layer_reshape(target_shape = c(depth,1)) %>%
    layer_conv_1d_transpose(filters=flt,kernel_size = c(kernels),strides = kernels/2 )%>% 
    layer_activation_leaky_relu(alpha=0.2) %>%
    layer_flatten() %>%
    #layer_conv_1d(filters = flt, kernel_size = c(kernels), strides = (kernel_size/2), activation = 'sigmoid') %>%
    layer_dense(depth,activation="sigmoid") %>%
    layer_reshape(target_shape = c(depth,1)) %>%
     recode_aa() %>%
    tf$squeeze(axis=-1L) %>%
  ?????????  my_conv()   ###### here I need help!!!
   
model=keras_model(inputs=prot_input2,outputs = GAN)  
    summary(model)
    return(model)
  }
#################### Build the model ####################

modelGAN=model_GAN(batch_size,flt,kernels,depth,rnd_seq)
```

The model works to the line: `tf$squeeze(axis=-1L)`

```
Model: "model_1"
___________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                                          Output Shape                                     Param #            
===========================================================================================================================
 input_12 (InputLayer)                                 [(None, 100)]                                    0                  
                                                                                                                           
 dense_19 (Dense)                                      (None, 809)                                      81709              
                                                                                                                           
 reshape_19 (Reshape)                                  (None, 809, 1)                                   0                  
                                                                                                                           
 conv1d_transpose_9 (Conv1DTranspose)                  (None, 4860, 8)                                  104                
                                                                                                                           
 leaky_re_lu_9 (LeakyReLU)                             (None, 4860, 8)                                  0                  
                                                                                                                           
 flatten_9 (Flatten)                                   (None, 38880)                                    0                  
                                                                                                                           
 dense_18 (Dense)                                      (None, 809)                                      31454729           
                                                                                                                           
 reshape_18 (Reshape)                                  (None, 809, 1)                                   0                  
                                                                                                                           
 tf.math.add_9 (TFOpLambda)                            (None, 809, 1)                                   0                  
                                                                                                                           
 tf.math.truediv_9 (TFOpLambda)                        (None, 809, 1)                                   0                  
                                                                                                                           
 tf.math.round_9 (TFOpLambda)                          (None, 809, 1)                                   0                  
                                                                                                                           
 tf.compat.v1.squeeze_9 (TFOpLambda)                   (None, 809)                                      0                  
                                                                                                                           
===========================================================================================================================
Total params: 31,536,542
Trainable params: 31,536,542
Non-trainable params: 0
___________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________
>
```

The final output is a sequence with shape `(None,809)`.

Now, I need to hot-encode the output within the model, so that the final output would be `(None ,809,22)`. I tried to add a pre-process layer using:

```
one_int<- layer_integer_lookup(vocabulary=dicint,
                                 oov_token = 0,
                                 num_oov_indices = 1L,
                                 output_mode = "one_hot")
```

dicint is my vocabulary. So, the last lines of the model are:

```
tf$squeeze(axis=-1L) %>%
  one_int()
```

But this solution does not work, because "layer_integer_lookup" does not encode in batch, raising an error:

```
*RuntimeError: Evaluation error: ValueError: Exception encountered when calling layer "integer_lookup_4" (type IntegerLookup).

When output_mode is not `'int'`, maximum supported output rank is 2. Received output_mode one_hot and input shape (None, 809), which would result in output rank 3.
Call arguments received:
â€¢ inputs=tf.Tensor(shape=(None, 809), dtype=float32)*
```

Then I tried to create a custom layer:

```
Convert_aa(keras$layers$Layer) %py_class% {
  initialize <- function(inputs) {
    super$initialize()
  }
  call <- function(inputs) {
    one_int(inputs)
  }   
}
my_conv=Convert_aa(inputs)
```

But it did not change the resulting error. I need your help. How can I hot-encode within the model?

Answer (score 0):

I think I understood part of the problem. I think that the one-hot encoding within the model do not allow gradient propagation, because integers are not differentiable. Then I created a workaround by approximating the one-hot encoding. Let's say that the last differentiable layer is a perceptron:

```
GAN=mlp(hidden_units=kwidth,dropout_rate = 0.1)
```

with size: (None,809,22)
First I evaluated the 809 max values along the last dimension:

```
a1=tf$math$reduce_max(GAN,axis=2L,keepdims=T) (None,809)
```

Then I expanded the max values to the second dimension creating a tensor of max values specular to the perceptron

```
a2 = tf$math$multiply(a1,tf$ones(22L)) (None,809,22)
```

Then I subtracted the max values from the perceptron, adding 1 and then a small epsilon.

```
sub=tf$math$subtract(GAN,a2) %>% 
   tf$math$add(10E-7) %>% 
   tf$math$add(1)(None,809,22)
```

At this point all the values are less than 1, except for the max value that accounts for 1+10E-7.
Then I applied a relu activation with threshold =1

```
layer_activation_relu(threshold=1)
```

So all the values but the max_values are zeroed. The resulting tensor (None,809,22) is all zeros but for each of the 809 slices one out of 22 values is 1+1E8.
One hot encoding is approximate, but at least it is trainable.
Any better solution??